# how to get index of row in original dataframe after applying unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe i am applying unique method on one its column but

```
for i in range(len(np.unique(first_group.Note_Detail))):
     s=np.unique(first_group.Note_Detail)[i]
     first_group.Insurance_Id[i]     
         t={}
for m in re.finditer(r'^(.+)(?:\r?\n\s*\[(.+)])?\r?$', s, re.M):


    if m.group(2):
        t1={}
        for sub_item in [x.strip() for x in m.group(2).strip().split('], [') if ':' in x]:
            itm=sub_item.split(':')
            itm1=itm[1].strip().split('to')
            t2={}
            if len(itm1)>1:
                t2['old']=itm1[0].strip()
                t2['new']=itm1[1].strip()
                t2['action']='Changed'
            elif len(itm1)==1 and itm[1].strip()=='Removed':
                t2['old']='Null'
                t2['new']='Null'
                t2['action']='Removed'    
            else:
                t2['old']='Null'
                t2['new']=itm1[0].strip()
                t2['action']='added'
            t1[itm[0].strip()]=t2   
#         t.append(t1)
        t[m.group(1).strip().split(':')[0]]=t1
    else:
        t[m.group(1).strip().split(':')[0]]='None'
#     print t    
   res[i]=[t,first_group.Insurance_Id[i],first_group.Patient_Id,first_group.Patient_Id,first_group.Created_By]
```

print res

> ---
>
> ```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-314-971c32825ccc> in <module>()
>      31             t[m.group(1).strip().split(':')[0]]='None'
>      32     #     print t
> ---> 33     res[i]=[t,first_group.Insurance_Id[i],first_group.Patient_Id,first_group.Patient_Id,first_group.Created_By]
>      34 print res
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
>     765         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
>     766         try:
> --> 767             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>     768 
>     769             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.pyc in
> ```
>
> get_value(self, series, key)
>          3116         try:
>          3117             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
>       -> 3118                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
>          3119         except KeyError as e1:
>          3120             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:
>
> ```
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 0
> ```

how to get index of first_group dataframe to access `first_group.Insurance_Id[i]`  inside loop

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: Try to use `first_group.loc[i].Insurance_Id` or `first_group.Insurance_Id.values[i]`